# TypeScript config for compiling different *.ts files each with referenced files?

Tags: typescript, gulp

I have a folder structure like this:

```
/ts
    /module1
        /partials
            partial1.ts
            partial2.ts
        module1.ts
        tsconfig.json
    /module2
        /partials
            partial1.ts
            partial2.ts
        module2.ts
        tsconfig.json
```

Each of the `module1.ts` and `module2.ts` files has referenced imports at the top. For example:

```
/// <reference path="partials/1.ts" />
/// <reference path="partials/2.ts" />
```

Each module has a `tsconfig.json` that looks like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {

    },
    "files": [
        "module1.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

I also have a 'standard' `tsconfig.json` file in the project root that looks like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "none",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "inlineSourceMap": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

What I want output is a js file for each module e.g. `module1.js` and `module2.js`. However, I am actually getting the entire ts folder exported as JS files.

The referenced files are not being processed into one. Instead they are being output with the same folder structure as the ts files. For example:

```
/build
    js/
        partials/
            partial1.js
            partial2.js
        module1.js
```

I am using gulp to compile my TypeScript. The task looks like this:

```
gulp.task("ts", function() {
    tsProject.src()
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(tsProject(reporter)).js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./build/js"));
});
```

How should I re-configure my project to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

try adding 'isolatedModules': true in system.config file